# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Access is denied. [COMException (0x80070005): Access is denied]

Tags: sharepoint, iis-7.5, sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2008, server

I need help regarding SharePoint 2007 with windows 2008 server OS. to give you a background the server is having a trust relationship error on our domain so we need to rejoin the server to the domain. after rejoining we encounter this error and found out that the IIS Admin Services is stopped and unable to start.

here is the error:

Access is denied.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Access is denied.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[COMException (0x80070005): Access is denied.
]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +557
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_IsContainer() +42
   System.DirectoryServices.ChildEnumerator..ctor(DirectoryEntry container) +36
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.GetEnumerator() +36
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +704
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +124
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +1162
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +312
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +133
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +196
```